# Run NUnit test fixture programmatically

Tags: c#, nunit

I often want to perform a quick test, and code it up in LINQPad.

So I have a `Main()` entry point. Can I make NUnit "run" a fixture programmatically from there?

```
using NUnit.Framework;

public class Runner
{

  public static void Main()
  {
    //what do I do here?
  }

  [TestFixture]
  public class Foo
  {

    [Test]
    public void TestSomething()
    {
      // test something
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [**NUnitLite Runner**](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner):

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnitLite;

public class Runner {


    public static int Main(string[] args) {
        return new AutoRun(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                       .Execute(new String[] {"/test:Runner.Foo.TestSomething"});
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class Foo {

        [Test]
        public void TestSomething() {
            // test something
        }
    }

}
```

Here `"/run:Runner.Foo"` specifies the text fixture.

Mind that you have to reference the `nunitlite.dll` package as well.

Comment: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'testAssembly' of 'AutoRun.AutoRun(Assembly)'`

Comment: Did you use a `String[]` array?

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting somewhere. Now it complains of not finding assembly `System.Console`. I guess there is only so far I can push LINQPad. It works on the command line though, but that's not friendly like LINQPad. I'll dig a little to see how to get that to work.

Comment: @grokky: I altered the code again. It is the executing assembly. Sorry...

Comment: I added `System.Console` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimInformation` nugets to LINQPad, and added your code. Now I get NUnit output, but it doesn't run the fixture: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.` I think it's not possible in LINQPad, only the command line. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @grokky: but have you written `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` instead of `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`? I made an error at that part.

Comment: The "normal" way to call AutoRun is to __not__ specify the executing assembly. NUnitLite itself will use GetCallingAssembly().

Comment: @Charlie: yeah that was what I had in mind. But I inspected the source code, and there are some precompiler directives that will in some cases ignore the default constructor.

Comment: @Charlie: see here https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/nunitlite/AutoRun.cs#L68

Comment: Ah! Got it. For our own tests, we use nunitlite-runner for those builds, specifying the assembly as an argument. Your answer is the best, with the exception that `/run` is an obsolete argument. Use `/test` with the latest code and remember you want the __full__ name of the test.

Comment: BTW, I'm on vacation answering from memory. Usual warnings apply. ;-)

Comment: @Charlie Do you think it's possible to run a test within an environment like LINQPad, or is it only possible from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

With 3.8, the problem that was introduced in 3.7 will be fixed. Whether that works explicitly with LINQPad, I'm not sure. You could try it out using the latest build from our MyGet feed.