# How to run TestFixture programatically with NUnit3

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I've been trying to figure out a good/best way to run a TestFixture programmatically but can't seem to find a way to do it with NUnit3. I followed a [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310571/run-nunit-test-fixture-programmatically) but it doesn't seem to work for me and it appears that's to run a specific test or list of tests which I may not have, all i have is the name of a TestFixture class.

I've also read through several posts which are quite old and refer to using things like TestRunner and TestPackage, etc which I gather are no longer available in NUnit3.  I can run/execute my test class using the command line and nunit3-console, is the approach i should be using here to invoke an executable from my program?

Comment: FYI:  your this post link is broken.

Comment: @MitchStewart Fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the ideal way to resolve this is to use NUnitLite AutoRun but I have not been able to get it working, therefore I opted for the option to invoke nunit3-console via Process

```
string nunit = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe";
        string assembly = @"C:\Path\to\assembly.dll";
        string testFixture = " --where class=" + fixtureToRun;
        string work = @" --work=C:\Path\to\store\results\";
        string args = assembly + testFixture + work;

        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(nunit, args);
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            process.Start();

            bool completed = process.WaitForExit(60000);

            string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Hopefully this helps someone out and I'm still open to suggestions for doing this in a more efficient fashion

Answer (score 0):

Referencing NUnitLite and creating a Main program is definitely an option for running tests directly. You must use the same version of the nunit framework and nUnitlite assemblies for this to work.

The calling sequence to NUnitLite's AutoRun test runner varies from version to version. You can use intellisense to check it. For 3.9, use code like this...

`new AutoRun().Execute(args);`

Notes:

1. The assembly is not needed as an argument to the constructor if the tests are in the same assembly.
2. If running from the command-line, `args` is the same argument array passed into your test executable.
3. If running programatically, whatever arguments you need as elements of the string array. Do not specify a filename. For example, pass `new string[] { "--test:Name.Of.MyFixture" }` to run a fixture.

Comment: I verified the assembly versions for nunit and nunitlite are the same. I tried a simple console app where the test fixture is in the same assembly as Main. NUnitLite is invoked correctly however no tests are found. I need to integrate into our current framework so if I was to go this route I need to use reflection to find the proper assembly to invoke, does the AutoRun constructor refer to the executing assembly or the assembly containing the test fixture?

Comment: The intention of nunitlite is to support self-executing tests. Your test assembly is an exe and calls AutoRun to run it's own tests. That's what the "auto" part means. No assembly should be specified when calling it. Passing an assembly was previously supported for testing purposes.

Comment: If you are __not__ trying to make a self-executing test, then I suggest posting a new question that doesn't have to do with NUnitLite. :-)