# Selenium NUnit run from Main() or exe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit

I want to run all selenium tests from an exe. I tried the solution mentioned on this thread ([Run NUnit test fixture programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310571/run-nunit-test-fixture-programmatically/45310723#45310723?newreg=0a811b0f9323428f99166add0ec60dde))

This is what I have written

```
   public class Runner{

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return new AutoRun(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
                   .Execute(new String[]{"/test:Runner.Foo.Login" });}

       [TestFixture]
       public class Foo
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [Test]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();// (@"C:\Selenium\Firefox");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = 
                  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Setup Browser");
        }
        [Test]
        public void Login()
        {
            eWb.Classes.LoginUser.eWbLogin(driver, ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UserId"],
                ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Password"], "CU");
           }}}}
```

The Console opens and is not able to read the test method Login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `Assembly.GetCallingAssemby()` as a constructor argument to `AutoRun`. Since this is in your Main, there is no calling assembly, so I assume the value passed is null. Being told to find tests in `null`, AutoRun is pretty much guaranteed not to find any.

The proper call is to pass no argument at all, since the tests are, in fact, in the assembly making the call. AutoRun itself will figure out what the calling assembly is and should find your tests.

The SO answer to which you list does not use `GetCallingAssembly`. It uses `GetExecutingAssembly`. However, since no argument works equally well, that's what I would use. In fact, with NUnit, you should generally use defaults first and only tailor arguments where it's necessary.

Suggest reading the documentation as well: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki

Comment: I would also add to Charlie's answer that your Initialize method should not be a [Test] but a [OneTimeSetup] so that it is run once before your tests.