# How can I run Nunit from another project

Tags: c#, dll, web-applications, nunit, dotnet-test

I have an NUnit project for testing automations called **TestManager** and I have created another Web App project called **TestManagerGateway** to enable end-users to invoke those tests using "dotnet test" command.

basically when invoking the REST API in the gateway, it simply trying to run the dotnet test command using the **TestManager** dll (*"dotnet test TestManager.dll"* - I was trying to use reference to the TestManager project dll from my TestMangerGateway project.

however, I realized this is not possible and I get a fatal error for "The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found..."

obviously, when using the full path to the **TestManager.dll** on the Nunit project (TestMAanger) does work, but I am afraid that when creating containers for both projects this method will not work.
how can I ensure that I can refer to the **TestManager** project when using this shell command once I build containers (docker containers) for both projects?

Comment: Hi Yossi, you've used "NUnit project dll" several times and I can't tell what you mean by it. Could be nunit.framework.dll, nunit.engine.dll, etc. or even your own test assembly. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: I have editted my question to clarify. hopefully it will be more clear.

Comment: Running NUnit tests programmatically has been discussed elsewhere on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45310571) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2825918). Have you gone through those other questions?

Comment: @srk no, I haven't seen these while searching. Thanks, I will take a look.